# Best practices for *reading* CSV files with multiple sections of different formats

Tags: csvhelper

I'm a very happy user of CsvHelper, which helps my software receive a very large text file that has ~24 sections, each of which has a different format. This is by far the most convenient way to get data out of a line-of-business application as a single file (CsvHelper is not involved in *creating* the file, only *reading* it).

Each line is prefixed by the *type* of the line, with a per-section header followed by per-section data. We use a tab as the delimiter.

Simple made-up example with teams and employees:

```
TEAM    ID      Name
TEAM    1       Engineering
TEAM    2       Janitorial
EE      ID      FName   LName   TeamId
EE      1       Bill    Gates   1
EE      2       Larry   Ellison 2
EE      3       Jeff    Bezos   1
```

I use a `TextReader` to fetch one line at a time from the file (the format cannot have multi-line fields), pull off the first token and save the line to a `MemoryStream`. When the token changes, it's a new section, so I feed the just-completed memory stream to CsvHelper in the ordinary way to produce my C# objects.

This has worked very reliably for some time.

But am I missing out on some cool CsvHelper way that could do this more directly in a single pass?

**EDIT** I'm not asking for alternate general coding ideas to solve this problem, which would generate a lot of opinions.

I'm asking if CsvHelper has any specific features on point for this specific use case that I have missed. I've studied the classmap stuff at some length and haven't found anything.

Comment: That's not a CSV file. As simple as that. CSV files have no sections. A CSV is a **simple** flat file format. It's abused by everyone, so CSV libraries try to handle eg missing columns, jagged files etc. What you posted though is anything but simple. Even a human would have trouble recognizing the two different *unseparated* sections

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, this is *clearly* an abuse of CSV, but it's what I have to work with and I don't get to change the universe to fit my needs.  If the best I can do is the way I'm doing it now (with memorystreams), then so be it. No harm in asking.

Comment: if you check the amount of code both answers contain, you may decide a hand-written parser would be better. Both answers try to detect the section based on heuristics and retrieve the record based on that. There's no "best practice" in this, just "does the job". Both answers can be improved (no reason to read the first field twice) but in the end, they do the same

Comment: Both of the below answers appear to be quite a bit better than what I'm doing now with all the memory-stream business, and as I have around two dozen record types (some of them with dozens of fields), the object reassembly of CsvHelper is way too much to recreate with my own hand parser.

Comment: You didn't post your code so I can't say. What both answers show is a common parsing technique though: use some sort of identifier to identify sections, then change the parsing mode for that section. Having faced such formats too (grouped Excel reports saved as "CSVs"), I'm *not* with any solution though. It's all too easy to break if someone decides to add another section or change a field name

Comment: Although in my case humans tried to "fix" stuff, so almost every file ended up with tiny differences in headers every month

Comment: The source format cannot change without my knowing about it - it comes from  report-writer program in the line-of-business app that's been tailored to this specific process of exporting data from one system where it can be imported to a different one. The alternative that does it "correctly" would have the customer run the export process two dozen times instead of one, and that's *far* worse than whatever complexity I have to deal with on the CSV front.

Comment: One could point to the big data formats like ORC or Parquet that handle such problems in a better way but that would be going too far. CsvHelperr has no way of switching modes automatically, so this is probably the best that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.AppendLine("TEAM  ID  Name");
    s.AppendLine("TEAM  1   Engineering");
    s.AppendLine("TEAM  2   Janitorial");
    s.AppendLine("EE    ID  FName   LName   TeamId");
    s.AppendLine("EE    1   Bill    Gates   1");
    s.AppendLine("EE    2   Larry   Ellison 2");
    s.AppendLine("EE    3   Jeff    Bezos   1");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";
        
        var rowType = RowType.None;     
        var foos = new List<Foo>();
        var bars = new List<Bar>();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            if (csv.GetField(1) == "ID")
            {
                csv.ReadHeader();
                
                if (csv.GetField(0) == "TEAM")
                {       
                    rowType = RowType.Foo;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (csv.GetField(0) == "EE")
                {           
                    rowType = RowType.Bar;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {           
                    rowType = RowType.None;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (rowType == RowType.Foo)
            {
                foos.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());
            }
            else if (rowType == RowType.Bar)
            {
                bars.Add(csv.GetRecord<Bar>());
            }
        }
        
        foos.Dump();
        bars.Dump();
    }
}

public enum RowType
{
    None = 0,
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 2
}

public class Foo
{
    [Name("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Name("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Name("FName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Name("LName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image]

If you have any questions, ask them in the comments and put more clarification above here.

Comment: Ha, I didn't even notice you had posted before I posted my answer. :) Looks like we had the same idea with slightly different implementations.  Only issue I see with this is the line `if (csv.GetField(1) == "ID")` Steve's actual data may not always have the same column name in the second position.

Comment: The first field is always the record type, and it's not included in record itself; not all records have an ID, but I get the idea; this looks right up my alley.

Comment: @DavidSpecht Ha! Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a "CsvHelper way" of doing it, but it might be close to what you are looking for.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("TEAM\tId\tName");
            writer.WriteLine("TEAM\t1\tEngineering");
            writer.WriteLine("EE\tId\tFirstName\tLastName\tTeamId");
            writer.WriteLine("EE\t1\tBill\tGates\t1");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\t";

            var teams = new List<Team>();
            var employees = new List<Employee>();
                
            var types = new Dictionary<string, ListType>
            {
                { "TEAM", new ListType{ Type = typeof(Team), List = teams} },
                { "EE", new ListType{ Type = typeof(Employee), List = employees} }
            };

            var lastType = string.Empty;
            var currentType = string.Empty;

            while (csv.Read())
            {
                currentType = csv.GetField<string>(0);

                if (!types.ContainsKey(currentType))
                    throw new Exception($"{currentType} is not a valid type");

                if (currentType == lastType)
                {
                    types[currentType].List.Add(csv.GetRecord(types[currentType].Type));
                }
                else
                {
                    csv.ReadHeader();
                }

                lastType = currentType;
            }                
        }
    }
}

public class ListType
{
    public IList List { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
}
```